# Transistor voltage rating?

Tags: transistors

Lets say i have a mosfet where the drain->source voltage is 100 but the gate->source voltage is 5. Do i need a transistor rated for 100v or 5v since at that gate voltage only 5v would pass through?

Also what happens to the other 95 volts in this scenario? Will they contribute to heating the transistor?

Also why does this red box keep whining about quality standards? It would help if it said anything other than "no".

EDIT: schematic

[image]

Comment: A schematic is probably needed here.

Comment: Well, English isn't my native language and it's not like I'm proposing to eat grandma here :D

Comment: Ok, I misunderstood your question. Didn't know 'transistor' was referring to the mosfet, thought you were trying to place another device

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You need a transistor rated >> 100V (consider Vds when Vgs=0)
2. Across the 10k resistor
3. Voltage doesn't heat, Volts x Current does. So the heating is Vdson . Ids
4. SE likes Qs to be more than perfunctory?

Comment: >>(consider Vds when Vgs=0)
oh that makes sense